# Alteração em css apenas em iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ios

Preciso fazer uma alteração de um css apenas no iOS, utilizei o

`if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {}`
 Porém não deu resultado.

O código que preciso alterar é esse.
`.sdn-music-player>.yt-wrap>iframe {
    left: -22px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -126px;`

Alguém sabe alguma maneira para fazer isso funcionar?

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso esse código para detectar, ele usa o **navigator.userAgent** e funciona legal. O código não é de minha autoria e infelizmente não tenho mais a referencia de onde encontrei o código na época. segue o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/mL2nrgg3/2/), testei no **Iphone 4** com **iOS 7**

```
function isIOS()
{    
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

    //Lista de dispositivos que acessar
    var iosArray = ['iphone', 'ipod'];

    var isApple = false;

    //valida seu array
    iosArray.forEach(function(item){

        if (ua.indexOf(iosArray[item]) != -1)
        {
            isApple = true;
        }

    });

    return isApple;
}

if(isIOS())
{
    $('seu seletor').css({
        'left': '-22px',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': '-126px'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Testei em alguns navegadores esse cod. e aparentemente funciona como um hack 
para safari em geral.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    ::i-block-chrome, "seuseletor" {
        attr: valor;
    }
}
```

Ex.:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    ::i-block-chrome, h1 {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Isso fará com que os elementos `h1` fiquem com coloração vermelha.

no seu caso:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    ::i-block-chrome, .sdn-music-player>.yt-wrap>iframe {
         left: -22px;
         position: absolute;
         top: -126px;
    }
}
```

Agora se tu precisar apenas pra um tamanho especifico de tela você pode associar mais uma condição para a `@media query`.

Ex.:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) and (min-width: 700px) { }
```

você pode ver mais exemplos de Mquery [aqui.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries)

Comment: Esse não seria o caso para usar as `@media querys `